# CUDA out of memory when running Bert with Pytorch (Previously worked)

Tags: pytorch, amazon-sagemaker, bert-language-model, spacy-transformers

I am building a BERT binary classification on SageMaker using Pytorch.

Previously when I ran the model, I set the Batch size to 16 and the model were able to run successfully. However, yesterday after I stopped SageMaker and restarted the this morning, I can't run the model with Batch size as 16 any more. I am able to run the model with batch size 8.
However, the model is not producing the same result (of course). I didn't change anything else in between. All other settings are the same. (Except I change the SageMaker volume from 30GB to 200GB.)

Does anyone know what may cause this problem? I really want to reproduce the result with batch size 16.

Any answers will help and thank you in advance!

Comment: Do verify if there are other processes running on the GPU.

Comment: @AshwinGeetD'Sa Thank you for your reply. I did found there are some other hidden python processes running in the back-end. However, I even stopped the SageMaker and restarted it. Should it just stops all the processes I have?

Comment: You can just check how much memory other processes are consuming. You can tentatively stop other processes and verify if you can run BERT.

Comment: Can you provide more details on where you are doing this within SageMaker?  Is this within a SageMaker NotebookInstance, a SageMaker TrainingJob, or something else?